# How to remap <cr> to go to line number in VSCodeVim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In vim I used to map the enter key `<cr>` to go to line number instead of the letter `G` using the following settings

```
nnoremap <expr> <cr> v:count == 0 ? "\<cr>" : "G"
```

**I tried to achieve the same result in vim for VSCode but I couldn't**.

Is there a way that manage me from doing so without enabling [the experimental feature neovim integration inside VSCode](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/README.md#neovim-integration)